# How change range slider to show money?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found this slider on [codepen](https://codepen.io/Melwee/pen/gOpPqvG) .

How do I get it to show me a minimum of € 500 and a maximum of € 6000 but to preserve the red background?

I have tried everything eg.

```
<input id = "range" type = "range" class = "range-slider" min = "500" max = "6000" step = "100">
```

But the range slider stretches to 6000% and I'm not good at JS.

```js
const rangeSlider = document.querySelector('.range-slider');
const rangeValueBar = document.querySelector('#range-value-bar');
const rangeValue = document.querySelector('#range-value');



let isDown = false;

function dragHandler() {
  isDown = !isDown;
  if (!isDown) {
    rangeValue.style.setProperty('opacity', '1');
  } else {
    rangeValue.style.setProperty('opacity', '1');
  }
}

function dragOn(e) {
  if (!isDown) return;
  rangeValueHandler();
}

function rangeValueHandler() {
  rangeValueBar.style.setProperty('width', `${rangeSlider.value}%`);
  rangeValue.innerHTML = `${rangeSlider.value}€`;
}

rangeValueHandler();
rangeSlider.addEventListener('mousedown', dragHandler);
rangeSlider.addEventListener('mousemove', dragOn);
rangeSlider.addEventListener('mouseup', dragHandler);
rangeSlider.addEventListener('click', rangeValueHandler);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 100px;
}
.range-slider-container {
  position: relative;
}

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#range-value-bar {
  width: 100%;
  content: "0";
  background-color: #FC6E50;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10000;
  height: 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
/**/
#range-value {
  width: 25px;
  content:"0";
  background: rgba(233, 239, 244, 0.1);;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10000;
  height: 25px;
  top: -65px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #41576B;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: #E9EFF4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  border: 14px solid #FFF;
  height: 53px;
  width: 53px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #FC6E50;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -13.5px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000000000;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 39px 0;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #000;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #000;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="range-slider-container">
  <input id="range" type="range" class="range-slider">
  <span id="range-value-bar"></span>
  <span id="range-value">0</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want, simply you can use min and max attributes for range slider form element, what I had to do is to remove width style in `rangeValueHandler` function.

I had to do the calculation for percentage for the width:

`((input - min_value) *100)/ (max_value - min_value)}%`

```js
const rangeSlider = document.querySelector('.range-slider');
const rangeValueBar = document.querySelector('#range-value-bar');
const rangeValue = document.querySelector('#range-value');



let isDown = false;

function dragHandler() {
  isDown = !isDown;
  if (!isDown) {
    rangeValue.style.setProperty('opacity', '1');
  } else {
    rangeValue.style.setProperty('opacity', '1');
  }
}

function dragOn(e) {
  if (!isDown) return;
  rangeValueHandler();
}

function rangeValueHandler() {
  percentage = `${((rangeSlider.value - 500) * 100) / (6000 - 500)}%`; 
  rangeValueBar.style.setProperty('width', percentage);
  rangeValue.innerHTML = `${rangeSlider.value}€`;
}

rangeValueHandler();
rangeSlider.addEventListener('mousedown', dragHandler);
rangeSlider.addEventListener('mousemove', dragOn);
rangeSlider.addEventListener('mouseup', dragHandler);
rangeSlider.addEventListener('click', rangeValueHandler);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 100px;
}
.range-slider-container {
  position: relative;
}

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#range-value-bar {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  content: "0";
  background-color: #FC6E50;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10000;
  height: 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
/**/
#range-value {
  width: auto;
  content:"0";
  background: rgba(233, 239, 244, 0.1);;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10000;
  height: 25px;
  top: -65px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #41576B;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: #E9EFF4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  border: 14px solid #FFF;
  height: 53px;
  width: 53px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #FC6E50;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -13.5px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000000000;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  /*width: 100%;*/
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 39px 0;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #000;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #000;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="range-slider-container">
  <input id="range" type="range" min="500" max="6000" class="range-slider">
  <span id="range-value-bar"></span>
  <span id="range-value">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but this is not the solution as this red background is not sliding

Comment: Sorry but it still doesn't work I need the background to be gray before and when I drag the slider the red background will pull

Answer (score 0):

Simply adapt the javascript that display the value:

```
function rangeValueHandler() {
  rangeValueBar.style.setProperty('width', `${rangeSlider.value}%`);
  const moneyValue = Math.round(500 + 5500 * rangeSlider.value * 0.01);
  rangeValue.innerHTML = `\$ ${moneyValue}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the limits min & max to any other value in this code its 500 & 6000

```js
const rangeSlider = document.querySelector('.range-slider');
const rangeValueBar = document.querySelector('#range-value-bar');
const rangeValue = document.querySelector('#range-value');



let isDown = false;

function dragHandler() {
  isDown = !isDown;
  if (!isDown) {
    rangeValue.style.setProperty('opacity', '1');
  } else {
    rangeValue.style.setProperty('opacity', '1');
  }
}

function dragOn(e) {
  if (!isDown) return;
  rangeValueHandler();
}
function rangeValueHandler() {
  min=500;  max=6000;
  rangeValueBar.style.setProperty('width',`${rangeSlider.value}%`);
  value = Math.round(min + (max-min) * (rangeSlider.value/100));
  rangeValue.innerHTML = `${value}€`;
}
rangeValueHandler();
rangeSlider.addEventListener('mousedown', dragHandler);
rangeSlider.addEventListener('mousemove', dragOn);
rangeSlider.addEventListener('mouseup', dragHandler);
rangeSlider.addEventListener('click', rangeValueHandler);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 100px;
}
.range-slider-container {
  position: relative;
}

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#range-value-bar {
  width: 100%;
  content: "0";
  background-color: #FC6E50;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10000;
  height: 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
/**/
#range-value {
  content:"0";
  background: rgba(233, 239, 244, 0.1);;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10000;
  height: 25px;
  top: -65px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  transform0: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #41576B;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: #E9EFF4;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
  border: 14px solid #FFF;
  height: 53px;
  width: 53px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: #FC6E50;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -13.5px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000000000;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 12.8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-width: 39px 0;
  color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #000;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: #000;
  border: 0px solid #000101;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #000000, 0px 0px 0px #0d0d0d;
  border: 0px solid #000000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 39px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="range-slider-container">
  <input id="range" type="range" class="range-slider">
  <span id="range-value-bar"></span>
  <span id="range-value">0</span>
</div>
```